# qt qwidgets that I create programmatically (such as Labels) never show, but ones that I create with the IDE work fine. I'm new to qt

Tags: qt

I'm new to QT.  when I create a qwidget such as a qlabel, programmatically,  it never shows in my main window or anywhere else.  But when I create one using the IDE it works fine.  What am I missing ?

Comment: Please provide your code, how are we supposed to know what's wrong with it otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

By default, widgets are set to invisible, therefore, you need to call `.show()` to make a widget visible. For example,

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel("click");
label->show();
```

Comment: That's not fully correct as this depends on the visibility state of the parent widget.
All widgets that are created before the parent is shown for the first time will show when the parent is, only widgets which are created after their parent has been shown need to be shown explicitly

Answer (score 0):

Using the debugger I noticed that my QLabel had the wrong parent.  Setting the parent correctly cured all of my problems.  The other answers to my question were relevant too.